# Is there any way to change the relative position of an object with css, and still be able to interact with it?

Tags: html, css

I made a navigation bar with HTML and then when I moved it upwards, it seems that it overlaps with another object and I cannot use it anymore.

```
.main-header-container {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    color:rgb(240, 240, 240);
    position:relative;
    top:-30px;
}
```

[This is the webpage that I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7WrI.png)

The logo is an image. When I hover over the navigation bar, it does not change color like it should, and I cannot click on it. I've tried to move it up and down, but the issue is that whenever I get it above a certain point I cannot interact with it. It's probably something thats really simple but i cant find anything online on how to fix it.

Edit: Heres the HTML:

```
<img src="SID-logos_transparent.png" alt="Should I Dodge?" style="width:100px;height:100px;">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Should I dodge?</title>
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navigation-bar-container">
        <li><a href="html/details.html">Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </div>
```

Comment: There might be some element blocking it, but it's impossible to tell which and why with the partial information you currently provided.

Comment: I highly suspect your `<img>` - all visible elements should be descendants of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: I tried to update that, but then I cant control the image size for some reason. It still doesnt allow me to interact with it though.

Comment: I don't see a reason for either of the issues, but please update the code in the question to the code you are using now. Even better, use the snippet tool and provide a minimal code that we can actually run and see the result.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try adding this line to your main-header-container:

z-index: 100